# Fetch API Doesn't send data on first call - NestJs

Tags: node.js, api, express, nestjs

I have an API in NestJs which is not sending data on the first hit. However, on hitting it again it sends the desired data. I am guessing the API returns before the internal processing is done.

How to stop this. Is sleep a good option for this?

Or is there any other way to do this?

```
@Post("load")
@UseGuards(AuthGuard("jwt"))
async load(@Req() body: any)
{           
    const organizationId = body.user.organizationId;
    const userId = body.user.userId;

    if ("brandIds" in body.body)
    {
        await this.userService.onBoardUser(userId);
    }

    var settings = await this.settingsService.fetchLayout(organizationId, "home");      

    settings.forEach(async (element) =>  
    {
        var parsedElement = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element));

        var innerContent = await this.fetchContent(parsedElement.method, organizationId, userId);           

        var template = parsedElement.content[0];
        let formattedItem = {};

        innerContent.forEach((item) =>
        {               
            try 
            {
                formattedItem = template;                                           

                Object.keys(template).forEach((key) => 
                {                                           
                    if (template[key]!= "" && key != "type")
                    {
                        formattedItem[key] = eval(template[key]);
                    }                       
                });

                parsedElement.content.push(formattedItem);
                formattedItem = null;
            }   
            catch(err)
            {

            }                                                   
        });

        this.response.data.push(parsedElement);

        innerContent = null;
        template = null;
        formattedItem = null;
        parsedElement = null;

    });

    return(this.response);
}
```

Comment: I was wondering if I could get a generalized answer if someone is facing this issue of API returning before processing ends.

Comment: @Talg123 edited the question and added the code above. Please have a look.

Comment: Ok, you need to understand that you can use async/await in foreach method.
change it to for...of

Answer (score 0):

looks like your main problem here is that your using async/await inside foreach which isnt working.
Use it like this:

```
for (const setting of settings) {
    ... your async code here.
}
```